# how to set vector and tensor symbols with horizontal bars above

Tags: vector, tensor

(Newbie) hi, how do I produce vector (text symbol(s)) with horizontal bar over it? Better, if possible, would be the `\rightharpoonup` mark above the letter (or word) that is the vector in question.(hope `\rightharpoonup` is the correct name for it).

I also have some tensor work to include - is there a package specifically for vector/tensor text?

At the moment I've added the `bm` package and that fine for bold vector symbol - but I prefer the one described above. 
thank you.

Comment: There is a `tensor` package indeed. The `\rightharpoonup` is lazy `physicist` vector style, in my point of view (I must know -- I am a lazy physicist ;-))

Comment: `\overset{\rightharpoonup}{x}`? Requires `amsmath`.

Comment: @egreg: I wanted to suggest that, but I don’t like the vertical spacing: it places the harpoon too high over the letter, IMHO.

Comment: Yes, it is a little on the high side - amazing to see the results  render so beautifully though  - l am only a couple of days into learning tex. OT Am trying several prep systems at the moment - ps I see tikz is a mere ~800 pages :-)

Answer (score 3):

Like this?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ascii]{inputenc}

\newcommand*{\ttensor}{\mathbin{\overline{\otimes}}}



\begin{document}
Text \( a\ttensor b \) text.
\end{document}
```

---

**Addendum:** I still owe you an answer to the question you actually asked.  Christian’s answer is very good, especially because it provides the extensible harpoons you seem to be asking for (when you speak of covering a whole word); but suppose you don’t like the font that the `fdsymbol` package uses for that, and you want to stick to “Computer Modern harpoons” (those found in positions `"28`, `"29`, `"2A`, and `"2B` of the `cmmi` font); with the help of the `amsmath` package, it isn’t difficult to manifacture the required commands “by hand”:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ascii]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter

\newcommand*\MY@leftharpoonupfill@{%
    \arrowfill@\leftharpoonup\relbar\relbar
}
\newcommand*\MY@rightharpoonupfill@{%
    \arrowfill@\relbar\relbar\rightharpoonup
}
% These are not needed, for now:
% \newcommand*\MY@leftharpoondownfill@{%
%   \arrowfill@\lefttharpoondown\relbar\relbar
% }
% \newcommand*\MY@rightharpoondownfill@{%
%   \arrowfill@\relbar\relbar\rightharpoondown
% }
\newcommand*\overleftharpoon{%
    \mathpalette{\overarrow@\MY@leftharpoonupfill@}%
}
\newcommand*\overrightharpoon{%
    \mathpalette{\overarrow@\MY@rightharpoonupfill@}%
}

\makeatother



\begin{document}

A formula: \(
    \overrightharpoon{x}:=\overrightharpoon{\textit{counter}}
\).  Another formula: \(
    \overleftharpoon{x}:=\overleftharpoon{\textit{counter}}
\).

\end{document}
```

And here’s the output:

[image: Output of the second code sample]

---

**Second addition:** On second thought, it occurred to me that perhaps the size of the covering harpoon is too big: it would look better in `\scriptstyle` size (when the main size is the text size).  This requires a bit more effort:

```
% My standard header for TeX.SX answers:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} % To avoid confusion, let us explicitly 
                                 % declare the paper format.

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         % Not necessary, but recommended.

\usepackage[ascii]{inputenc}     % Just to check that the source is still pure,
                                 % 7-bit-clean ASCII when you execute it, as it
                                 % was when I wrote it.
% End of standard header.  What follows pertains to the problem at hand.

\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter

\newcommand*\MY@leftharpoonupfill@{%
    \arrowfill@\leftharpoonup\relbar\relbar
}
\newcommand*\MY@rightharpoonupfill@{%
    \arrowfill@\relbar\relbar\rightharpoonup
}
% These are not needed, for now:
% \newcommand*\MY@leftharpoondownfill@{%
%   \arrowfill@\lefttharpoondown\relbar\relbar
% }
% \newcommand*\MY@rightharpoondownfill@{%
%   \arrowfill@\relbar\relbar\rightharpoondown
% }
\newcommand*\overleftharpoon{%
    \mathpalette{\overarrow@\MY@leftharpoonupfill@}%
}
\newcommand*\overrightharpoon{%
    \mathpalette{\overarrow@\MY@rightharpoonupfill@}%
}

% Support for smaller size arrows:
\newcommand*\@dblsty@mathpalette[2]{%
    % Works like "\mathpalette", but macro passed in #1 must take
    % (at least) three arguments, of which the first _two_ are
    % style selections.
    \mathchoice
        {#1\displaystyle       \scriptstyle       {#2}}%
        {#1\textstyle          \scriptstyle       {#2}}%
        {#1\scriptstyle        \scriptscriptstyle {#2}}%
        {#1\scriptscriptstyle  \scriptscriptstyle {#2}}%
}
\newcommand*\@dblsty@overarrow@[4]{%
    % #1 := stretchable covering arrow
    % #2 := base style
    % #3 := style for covering arrow
    % #4 := base symbol
    \vbox{\ialign{##\crcr
        #1#3\crcr
        \noalign{\nointerlineskip}%
        $\m@th\hfil #2#4\hfil$\crcr
    }}%
}
\newcommand*\smalloverleftharpoon{%
    \@dblsty@mathpalette{\@dblsty@overarrow@\MY@leftharpoonupfill@}%
}
\newcommand*\smalloverrightharpoon{%
    \@dblsty@mathpalette{\@dblsty@overarrow@\MY@rightharpoonupfill@}%
}

\makeatother



\begin{document}

\section{Normal size}

A formula: \(
    \overrightharpoon{x}:=\overrightharpoon{\textit{counter}}
\).  Another formula: \(
    \overleftharpoon{x}:=\overleftharpoon{\textit{counter}}
\).

\section{Smaller size}

A formula: \(
    \smalloverrightharpoon{x}:=\smalloverrightharpoon{\textit{counter}}
\).  Another formula: \(
    \smalloverleftharpoon{x}:=\smalloverleftharpoon{\textit{counter}}
\).

\end{document}
```

In the output, you can compare the two sizes and choose your preferred one.  Be aware, however, that the smaller size is inconsistent with the other uses of “over-arrows” in the `amsmath` package.

[image: Output of the third code sample]

---

**Third addition:**  It should be noted that (a robust version of) the two commands `\overleftharpoon` and `\overrightharpoon` is defined, in *exactly* the same way as shown above, by the `MnSymbol` package.  On the other hand, as far as I know the “small” variants are genuine new ones.

Comment: @jss: No, I have probably misunderstood your question.  If so, I’ll delete my answer.

Comment: That's useful in itself and certainly related. thanks

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti I'm looking for such a way to typeset vector. Your "smaller size" looks very good for me. But I didn't success, do you know why the bar splits? http://imgur.com/a/tSoCi

Comment: @Eric: The extensible harpoon is rendered by juxtapposing as many minus characters as needed to give the desired length, plus a special character for the harpoon tip.  (pdf)TeX computes the *exact* position of all these characters so that they will line up properly, but sometimes the (PDF) previewer misaligns them slightly due to errors in rounding their position to pixels.  It is a mere defect of the previewer that should disappear in print.

Comment: @Gustavo Mezzetti I see! Thanks for your explanation. And this is the best way(look) to typeset vector symbol that I see in the internet.

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti I come back to this question again. I extracted the minus symbol `-` from `txfonts` by `\DeclareSymbolFont{vvsymbols}{OMS}{txsy}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{vvsymbols}{bold}{OMS}{txsy}{bb}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{-}{\mathbin}{vvsymbols}{0}`. And in this case, the bar really splits, even in print. I think this is due to the change of the minus sign which leads to the inconsistency. I tried to modify the code, but I can't figure out the critical part that I should modified. May I ask for your help? :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `accents` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{accents}

\begin{document}

$\accentset{\rightharpoonup}{x}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A solution with `fdsymbol`, using `\overrightharpoon`:

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{fdsymbol}


\begin{document}

$\overrightharpoon{A}$
$\overrightharpoon{All}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

There's also the `harpoon` package and `\overrightharp{A}` but this does produce weird symbols, in my point of view.

Please have a look on `esvect` package as well, with provides nice vector arrows as accents.