# Working to find Latex error – Redefinition Problem

Tags: packages, amsmath

Working to find Latex error – Redefinition Problem

I have been trying-out the several ways of writing a vector symbol with harpoon above, - as described in several replies to an early post ref:
[how to set vector and tensor symbols with horizontal bars above](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/304622/how-to-set-vector-and-tensor-symbols-with-horizontal-bars-above/304637#304637)

They all worked fine and I was simply experimenting, commenting out the various alternatives to see the effect of each - then suddenly started getting a compilation error:-

```
“! LaTeX Error: Command `\vec' already defined.”
```

Alas due to the ad hoc way I was trying out each vector symbol I am not quite sure how I managed to get this error. Simply undoing the last commented-out section should of course “fix it” – but that doesn’t seem to be the case! The strange thing is, that those different ways to draw that vector still appeared (correctly rendered) in the .pdf output. I must have added something to cause the redefinition error – but after much searching I cannot see what it is!

Resorted to looking for said symbol, `\vec`, in the `\usepackage{}`  `.sty` files. And found, `\vec` it is defined in both `amsmath.sty` and `fdsymbol.sty`.  The problem now is how to correct this situation?

Are such redefinitions (collisions) commonplace in a miktex build which presumably has many `\usepackage{}`? Or if not, how do each of the “identifiers” (excuse lack of correct terminology) maintain a unique presence in an overall `.tex` build? Do Tex systems have any methods in place to handle collisions of symbol names?

To summarize my questions:
1.  how to correct this redefinition error
2.  how should I proceed in future with regard to general `TeX` usage in relation to avoiding the redefinition problem in `\usepackage`s

HERE IS THE ERROR INFORMATION

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

```
"C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\fdsymbol\fdsymbol.sty

! LaTeX Error: Command `\vec' already defined.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.Type H <return> for immediate help
.... ...ccent{\vec}{\mathord}{largesymbols}{"84}

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

In fdsymbol.sty, line 1799 has:-
\DeclareMathAccent{\vec}{\mathord}{largesymbols}{"84}
```

Thank you

Comment: I get no conflicts with `\documentclass{article}                                    
\usepackage{fdsymbol}                                                   
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$\vec x$
\end{document}`

Comment: In general, however, to overcome a redundant symbol load, after loading the first package, `\let\macroname\relax` where `\macroname` is the redundant symbol.  Then load the 2nd package, whose definition will prevail.

Comment: Also, with compilation issues such as you describe, deleting the `aux` file and any other auxiliary files before recompilation will frequently correct the issue.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you [indent lines by 4 spaces](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863), they'll be marked as code. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Answer (score 2):

I have been asked to summarize my comments into an answer.  As it is, I have no problem compiling

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{fdsymbol} 
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\begin{document} 
$\vec x$ 
\end{document}
```

However, there is a technique to use, if two packages both wish to define the same named symbol (or macro).  That is, once the first package is loaded, you can "undefine" the conflicted symbol (let us say, in this case, `\vec`) with the syntax

```
\let\vec\relax
```

Then, you can load the 2nd package without complaint/warning.

The other point I mentioned in comments is that the `aux` file that is created on one run is imported for the subsequent 2nd-pass compilation.  Thus, if things went awry during any stage of the effort, remnants of the problem could remain hidden in the `aux` file, even if the source `tex` file is corrected.  Thus, it is highly recommended, in such cases, to remove `aux` file prior to recompilation attempts.  This same advice often pertains to other adjunct files associated with compilation, but most often the fault lies in the `aux` file.