# How to modify the \relbar?

Tags: amsmath

I want to typeset vectors with `\rightharpoonup` heads. I found that the most ideal solution is [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/304624/97035), where the author uses `-` to fill the overline when the body is lengthy.

However, I'm now using math time professional 2, and due to its bigger looking plus/minus sign, I had redefined the minus sign, `-`, borrowing from `txfonts`. The code is:

```
\DeclareSymbolFont{vvsymbols}{OMS}{txsy}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{vvsymbols}{bold}{OMS}{txsy}{bb}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{-}{\mathbin}{vvsymbols}{0}
```

And then the bar became splits.
[image]

How can I solve this? Should I redefine the command `\relbar`? Or should I temporarily specify the `-` to be the original one within that vector command? How to do that?

**Code**

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,openany,fleqn]{book}
\usepackage[margin=2cm, top=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[subscriptcorrection,nofontinfo,zswash,mtphrb]{mtpro2} %this could be commented
\parindent=0pt
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\MY@leftharpoonupfill@{%
    \arrowfill@\leftharpoonup\relbar\relbar
}
\newcommand*\MY@rightharpoonupfill@{%
    \arrowfill@\relbar\relbar\rightharpoonup
}
% These are not needed, for now:
% \newcommand*\MY@leftharpoondownfill@{%
%   \arrowfill@\lefttharpoondown\relbar\relbar
% }
% \newcommand*\MY@rightharpoondownfill@{%
%   \arrowfill@\relbar\relbar\rightharpoondown
% }
\newcommand*\overleftharpoon{%
    \mathpalette{\overarrow@\MY@leftharpoonupfill@}%
}
\newcommand*\overrightharpoon{%
    \mathpalette{\overarrow@\MY@rightharpoonupfill@}%
}

% Support for smaller size arrows:
\newcommand*\@dblsty@mathpalette[2]{%
    % Works like "\mathpalette", but macro passed in #1 must take
    % (at least) three arguments, of which the first _two_ are
    % style selections.
    \mathchoice
    {#1\displaystyle       \scriptstyle       {#2}}%
    {#1\textstyle          \scriptstyle       {#2}}%
    {#1\scriptstyle        \scriptscriptstyle {#2}}%
    {#1\scriptscriptstyle  \scriptscriptstyle {#2}}%
}
\newcommand*\@dblsty@overarrow@[4]{%
    % #1 := stretchable covering arrow
    % #2 := base style
    % #3 := style for covering arrow
    % #4 := base symbol
    \vbox{\ialign{##\crcr
            #1#3\crcr
            \noalign{\nointerlineskip}%
            $\m@th\hfil #2#4\hfil$\crcr
    }}%
}
\newcommand*\smalloverleftharpoon{%
    \@dblsty@mathpalette{\@dblsty@overarrow@\MY@leftharpoonupfill@}%
}
\newcommand*\smalloverrightharpoon{%
    \@dblsty@mathpalette{\@dblsty@overarrow@\MY@rightharpoonupfill@}%
}
\newcommand*\myvec{%
    \@dblsty@mathpalette{\@dblsty@overarrow@\MY@leftharpoonupfill@}%
}

\makeatother
\DeclareSymbolFont{vvsymbols}{OMS}{txsy}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{vvsymbols}{bold}{OMS}{txsy}{bb}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{-}{\mathbin}{vvsymbols}{0}
\begin{document}
$1+1=2=3-1$ (You can see the minus sign became smaller.)\\
$\overrightharpoon{AB}:=\overrightharpoon{\textit{counter}}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you add a full MWE so we can easily reproduce the problem?

Comment: OK, I'm now going to do this. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It happens because the `amsmath` package says

```
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \mathchardef\std@minus\mathcode`\-\relax
  \mathchardef\std@equal\mathcode`\=\relax
}
```

and this causes `\std@minus` to be reset to the new value (`\mathchar "2400"`), that points to the minus sign in the new font, at the beginning of your document.  It suffices to counteract this setting, so that the original value `\mathchar "2200` is reinstated.  This can be done as follows:

```
\@ifdefinable\ORG@std@minus{\let\ORG@std@minus\std@minus}
\DeclareSymbolFont{vvsymbols}{OMS}{txsy}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{vvsymbols}{bold}{OMS}{txsy}{bb}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{-}{\mathbin}{vvsymbols}{0}
\AtBeginDocument{\let\std@minus\ORG@std@minus}
```

Here is a full, compilable example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,openany,fleqn]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[margin=2cm, top=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\parindent=0pt

\makeatletter

\newcommand*\MY@leftharpoonupfill@{%
    \arrowfill@\leftharpoonup\relbar\relbar
}
\newcommand*\MY@rightharpoonupfill@{%
    \arrowfill@\relbar\relbar\rightharpoonup
}
% These are not needed, for now:
% \newcommand*\MY@leftharpoondownfill@{%
%   \arrowfill@\lefttharpoondown\relbar\relbar
% }
% \newcommand*\MY@rightharpoondownfill@{%
%   \arrowfill@\relbar\relbar\rightharpoondown
% }
\newcommand*\overleftharpoon{%
    \mathpalette{\overarrow@\MY@leftharpoonupfill@}%
}
\newcommand*\overrightharpoon{%
    \mathpalette{\overarrow@\MY@rightharpoonupfill@}%
}

% Support for smaller size arrows:
\newcommand*\@dblsty@mathpalette[2]{%
    % Works like "\mathpalette", but macro passed in #1 must take
    % (at least) three arguments, of which the first _two_ are
    % style selections.
    \mathchoice
    {#1\displaystyle       \scriptstyle       {#2}}%
    {#1\textstyle          \scriptstyle       {#2}}%
    {#1\scriptstyle        \scriptscriptstyle {#2}}%
    {#1\scriptscriptstyle  \scriptscriptstyle {#2}}%
}
\newcommand*\@dblsty@overarrow@[4]{%
    % #1 := stretchable covering arrow
    % #2 := base style
    % #3 := style for covering arrow
    % #4 := base symbol
    \vbox{\ialign{##\crcr
            #1#3\crcr
            \noalign{\nointerlineskip}%
            $\m@th\hfil #2#4\hfil$\crcr
    }}%
}
\newcommand*\smalloverleftharpoon{%
    \@dblsty@mathpalette{\@dblsty@overarrow@\MY@leftharpoonupfill@}%
}
\newcommand*\smalloverrightharpoon{%
    \@dblsty@mathpalette{\@dblsty@overarrow@\MY@rightharpoonupfill@}%
}
\newcommand*\myvec{%
    \@dblsty@mathpalette{\@dblsty@overarrow@\MY@leftharpoonupfill@}%
}

\@ifdefinable\ORG@std@minus{\let\ORG@std@minus\std@minus}
\DeclareSymbolFont{vvsymbols}{OMS}{txsy}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{vvsymbols}{bold}{OMS}{txsy}{bb}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{-}{\mathbin}{vvsymbols}{0}
\AtBeginDocument{\let\std@minus\ORG@std@minus}

\makeatother



\begin{document}

$1+1=2=3-1$ (You can see the minus sign became smaller.)\\
Yet the harpoons come out right:
$\overrightharpoon{AB}:=\overrightharpoon{\textit{counter}}$

\end{document}
```

You can check by yourself that the output is what you asked for:

[image: Output of the code]

**Please note** that this answer assumes that, for some reason of yours, which I cannot understand, you want to replace only the minus sign, but without switching to a new set of math fonts.

Comment: It works! I use `mtpro2` and extract `+` from `newtxmath`(where `-` from `txfonts`; I noted that `newtxmath` also uses `txfont`'s `-`). My commands are [these](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/354431/extract-the-plus-symbol-from-newtxmath). I want the times-like math font to suit the text, so I first tried `mtpro2`. But the only unsuited thing is the bigger looking `+`,`-`, `\times`, etc. So I came up with extracting some binary operations from other times-like fonts, such as those mentioned.

Comment: But extracting the symbols one at a time is cumbersome, so I had tried to require the whole sets in `newtxmath`. I tried to read the document of `newtxmath`, figuring out which symbol sets corresponding to which commands. However, I'm not good at LaTeX, so it is too difficult/advanced for me. I never succeed. As you said, how can I switch to a new set of math fonts?