# Straight Harpoon Head

Tags: math-mode, arrows

The question is very simple, though who knows how complicated the answer will be.

[image]

How do I obtain something resembling the right figure? I do not like the curved look of the harpoon head.

Note I already have the command defined to obtain the figure on the left, which simply uses \rightharpoonup as it is.

Comment: Could you add an MWE with the code you use for the figure on the left?

Comment: Maybe https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/304637/ does what you want?